# High power 11 to 22Khz amplifier

Tags: high-frequency

I have built a circuit using a 555 IC. (Oops sorry)The purpose is to control the neighbours barking dogs. The output varies between 11 and 22kHz by means of a pot to have the most effect. What are the requirements to amplify an ultrasonic signal in this range. The amplifier will only be used in this range, as powerful as possible. Where do I find a downloadable circuit diagram for an suitable amplifier? Any advice or recommendations will be appreciated.
Thanks, Arnold.

Comment: I recommend you don't do this. It will annoy a lot of people and possibly get you a citation. And it may have no effect on the dogs anyway.

Comment: Did you try a plain audio amplifier? Most should reach around 20kHz.

Comment: What's a '666' IC? Not to be too hexakosioihexekontahexaphobic but I've not heard of it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It's a 555 gone over to the dark side.....

Comment: Does your neighbor know about this? Your project seems ethically questionable.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - It's the Devil's work, I tell you! A spawn of Satan that takes speakers into realms they were never meant to go, and drives men and dogs insane!

Comment: LOL, amplifier using 666 IC, producing the devil's sound.

Comment: Ooops Sorry about the 666!! It DOES work. I have a hand-held one, powered by a 9v battery. It stops a dog in its tracks, even at 30 feet....

Comment: That range is not considered ultrasonic. It will also "control" any teanagers in the area...

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be asking is "how can I amplify an ultrasonic audio signal?" The answer is "exactly the same way as any other audio signal."

First off, 11 - 22 kHz is not the right frequency range for this application. It's not even ultrasonic. [Here's a 15kHz tone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITyKEf4bu0I). It is audible to anybody with good hearing under the age of 30, so you will irritate quite a few people with your device. Dogs can hear all the way up to 60 kHz, so something in the 30-40 kHz region is more reasonable.

As for amplifying the signal, it depends how much power you need. The easiest solution is the good old [LM386](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) audio amplifier IC, which with no output capacitor has flat voltage gain of 20dB up to 100 kHz.

If you need more power than the LM386 can provide (about half a watt off a 9V supply), then you can look into other amplifier configurations. There are plenty of guides online for building class AB push-pull amplifiers with complementary transistors, which gets you a theoretical maximum of 78% efficiency. If you need even more power, then you can look at rolling your own Class-D amplifier board - TI has a good line of automotive Class-D amplifier controllers.

Now, as somebody who likes dogs, I should warn you - this is really not something you should leave on, nor is it something you should operate other than on your property. Dogs have really good hearing, so it's irresponsible to leave it on as an area denial system on your yard unless you have measured the sound pressure level at the edge of your property and determined that it's comparable to the background noise. Blasting the neighborhood with it would be pretty torturous to the animals. Put it on a switch, or on a motion detector, then you can trigger it briefly when dogs are about to crap on your lawn.